# Filling DataGrid Columns w/ Excel Data in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, ado.net, oledb

Alright, I finally got this code to work after hours of toiling:

```
        Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim myDataset As New DataSet()
        Dim strConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""")
        Dim myData As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", strConn)
        myData.Fill(myDataset)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataset.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

Now that I figured that out I was going to try and place the data in a specific location. On my application I have a datagridview set up with 4 columns. What I would like to do is put column A of the excel file under the 1st column of the datagridview and column C of the Excel File in the second column of the datagridview.

So replace:

```
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataset.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

with:

```
    DataGridView1.columns(0) = myDataset.Tables(0).columns(0)
    DataGridView1.columns(1) = myDataset.Tables(0).columns(2)
```

Obviously this doesnt work, and something tells me I might need a for loop to import the data, but I have never imported information from an Excel file before and to make it worse I have never worked with datagridviews before so I have no idea how to go about this.

I would like to do something like this if I could:

```
        For x = 1 To xldoc.rows.length - 1
            DataGridView1.Item(0, x).Value = CType(xlDoc.Cells(0, x + 1), Excel.Range).Text
        Next
```

Comment: I solved it. I will post my answer when I finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up being way easier to import the data. Im posting this in case anyone else comes across this thread.

```
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        xLApp = New Excel.Application
        xLBook = xLApp.Workbooks.Open(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        xLSheet = xLBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For x = 1 To xLSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            DataGridView1.Item(0, x - 1).Value = xLSheet.Cells(1 + x, 1).value
            DataGridView1.Item(1, x - 1).Value = xLSheet.Cells(1 + x, xLSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).value
        Next
    End If
```

Dont even bother with:

```
    Dim myDataset As New DataSet()
    Dim strConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""")
    Dim myData As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", strConn)
```

Comment: Thank you thank you Thank you. i was stuck for 4 days regarding gridviews and manually adding each row but you made me realize how easy looping through this damn excel sheet was. you rock buddy @Nefariis

Answer (score 0):

Think of it *roughly* as follows:

- Excel Work book = Database
- Excel Work sheet = Table
- Each Excel column = Table column
- Each Excel row = Table row
- Excel cell = a particular column value in a particular row

If your Excel has column headers, those are your field names. Now change your SQL query to select the columns you want and bind as usual.

Comment: The data starts on row 8, the header is on row 7, and the data could be anywhere from 2 lines to 15 lines. Would it be easier just to stop using excel and switch back to CSV's? CSV's seemed to be much less of a headache

Comment: If using CSVs is possible, go for it. Otherwise, make a copy of your Excel file, delete the first 6 rows (through the program), save the file and you should be good to go.