# Using a excel range in an oledb select statement

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, oledb

In VB.net, I'm reading one column of a larger excel spreadsheet into a datagrid using oledb.  A normal select statement for reading an entire sheet would look something like this:

```
da2 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [sheet3$]", cn)
```

For reading a single column from a larger sheet, this works:

```
da2 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [sheet3$A:A" & lastrow & "]", cn) 'this reads the entire column A down to the integer value in the variable 'lastrow'
```

My goal, now, is to read the entire sheet with a loop, column by column, by turning the sheet reference into a string OR get vb.net to concatenate/cast a string and range (which it won't).  I've tried these options, so far without success:

```
For colindex = 2 To lastcol3
colrange = xlWsheet3.Range(xlWsheet3.Cells(toprow, colindex), xlWsheet3.Cells(lastrow3.colindex)
addy = colrange.Address
da2 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [sheet3$" & addy & "]", cn)
```

No matter what I try, it always comes down to the fact that the oledb adapter just won't reconcile a string with an excel.range.  Is there an easier way to read a single column from excel by looping?  I'm new to programming, so any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've ditched the oledb column-by-column loop, and instead have just gone with a straight excel.interop loop, via this post:

[Filling DataGrid Columns w/ Excel Data in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876427/filling-datagrid-columns-w-excel-data-in-vb)

I don't think oledb was meant for very detailed/complicated reading...